# Spree 0.50.0 Error registering calculator Calculator::PriceBucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to configure Spree on Heroku, I have the website running
offline using thin but every now and again it will throw the error

> "Error registering calculator Calculator::PriceBucket"

I have tried setting config.cache_classes to both on and off

Also my gem file is configured as shown

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Generic gem dependencies first
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development
gem 'aws-s3'

# Followed by spree itself first, all spree-specific extensions second
gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git'    
gem 'spree_active_shipping', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_active_shipping.git'
gem 'spree_product_assembly', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree-product-assembly.git'
gem 'spree_static_content', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_static_content.git'
gem 'spree_heroku', '1.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/paxer/spree-heroku.git'
# EOFs
```

As is suggested here http://railsdog.lighthouseapp.com/projects/31096/tickets/1777-error-registering-calculator-calculatorpricebucket

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm just wondering, is there a reason you're using the git repos for each gem instead of released versions? You're basically using the latest code for spree and it's extensions. It might be hard to debug b/c each gem is a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps to you... [price-bucket-calculator](http://groups.google.com/group/spree-user/browse_thread/thread/873fbcbda0bc584f)

Comment: Im not entirely sure where to place the following code, I have done a checkout on the meesh gem and placed it in a src folder but cannot find the price_bucket.rb code to place the "fix"

Comment: look at /app/models/calculator/price_bucket.rb

Comment: I have edited the file as show here https://gist.github.com/925139 however I am still getting the same error message within the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing gem load order in the gemfile as specified at following URL:

http://railsdog.lighthouseapp.com/projects/31096/tickets/1777-error-registering-calculator-calculatorpricebucket